# Deleting rows that have no referring rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with a fk constraint to the table pk.

I want to delete all rows that has no relation to it.

Is there a way to skip the rows that has a constraint violation and remove all others.

Perhaps a loop with a transaction for each row..

Comment: If you have a foreign key constraint, then there are no rows that violate the constraint.  I might interpret your question as "deleting rows that have no referring rows", but clarification on your part would improve the question.

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: delete from PK table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to delete all rows in `pk` that have no referring rows.  If so:

```
delete from pk
    where not exists (select 1
                      from fk
                      where fk.fk = pk.pk
                     );
```

Note:  You do *not* want to use `not in` here, because `fk.fk` could be `NULL`.

Comment: Hi, in my case there are 4 tables that can have a ref to pk, Can I add an "and" in your example.

Comment: @jrb . . . Yes.  You should add 4 `not exist` clauses all connected with `and`.